# Can't get the order by working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this query:

```
     EDITED
```

The problem is that after executing the query I'm getting this error:

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.*

I am missing somthing?

Comment: You **cannot** have an `ORDER BY` in the individual parts of a `UNION` - you need to first `UNION` everything together - **then** you can add a single `ORDER BY` at the end to order the whole result set.

Comment: these are 2 queries wich are the same. The only thing changing is the `ROLE` I posted the whole thing, because you can imagane where the syntax error is.

Comment: Uh-oh, no human can read it, you have to do something to make it clear. Maybe you should create a temporary table and split the process to multiple steps. If you solve that syntax error, you won't sure that it really does what you want.

Comment: @marc_s It worked! I knew there is somthing small!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) at:

```
C. Using UNION of two SELECT statements with ORDER BY
```

you'll see that you can't use **ORDER BY** in the first query.

Remember that:

- number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.
- data types must be compatible.